# Sometimes I get from socket not what I expect

Tags: perl, sockets, tomcat, servlets, virtual-machine

I get socket handle to Httpd, the host is"127.0.0.1",the port is 80;

```
sub getHttpNetSock {
    my $client = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto     => "tcp",
                                    PeerAddr  => $host,
                                    Blocking  => 1,
                                    PeerPort  => $port)
        or return($client);
    $client->autoflush(1);              # so output gets there right away
    return($client);
}
```

After this if I am able to connect I try to get info from socket.

```
$ch = getHttpNetSock($apachePort);
if ($ch) {
$ret = getSockVal($ch, $apachePort);
}
```

where getSockVal:

```
sub getSockVal {
    my $sock = shift;
    print $sock "GET http://127.0.0.1:80/test/servlet/HealthServlet\n";   
    my $val= <$sock>;
    chomp($val);
    return($val);
}
```

HealthServlet could return just "OK" or "TROUBLE", but in one of 100 cases I get absolutely another information. Why it could happen?
Apache and perl scripts are on the VMware virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you just want a GET-Request you need not resort to IO::Socket::INET and handle HTTP, let LWP do that for you.

For easy error checking the preferred way would be with LWP::UserAgent, as described here:

http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, cannot change code. I just want to know the reason

Comment: Okay, do you have some samples of the unexpected output, that you can post?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have just the first line of the respounce ("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?"), because we use chomp for respounce. Looks like this is another package.I am wondering how this package can get there. I guessed that if you open the socket then no one can use it.